# How to start checking for click after a button is clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to start checking if you click on an image, but only after you click on a button.
Before the button is clicked, nothing should happen when you click on the image.
This is my code:

```
    <body>
        <div class="wrap" id="myImgId">
            {{-- <div class="draggable"></div> --}}
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="buttonClicked()">Click me</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function buttonClicked(){
            var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
            myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates;
        };
        </script>
    </body>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable with `false` value as flag, clicking on button you can set that to `true` which you can check when the image is clicked.

**Demo:**

```js
let clikedButton = false;
function buttonClicked(){
  clikedButton = true;
  var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
  //myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates;
};
document.querySelector('#myImgId').addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(clikedButton) {
    alert('clicked after the button');
    clikedButton = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrap" id="myImgId">
    Some Image
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="buttonClicked()">Click me</button>
```